# apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded

Tags: nginx, apache-httpd

I removed apache2 as it was giving error:

> AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.

then I reinstalled it, using `apt-get install apache2`
but now it gives error:

> apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
>   Action 'start' failed.

I have also installed nginx, is that a problem?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you are missing the apache2.conf which usually has no content.

Please try to create it using

```
touch /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and start your web server using this command

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```